# Why won't my countdown timer start and stop?

Tags: javascript, counter, countdown, countdowntimer

I need to make a simple countdown timer from 5 to zero, with the buttons to START and STOP the counter. The only thing that I don't know is that why won't my counter stop.

The code is presented below:

```js
   function clock() {
     var myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
     var c = 5;

     function myClock() {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
       if (c == 0) {
         clearInterval(myTimer);
         alert("Reached zero");
       }
     }
   }
```

```html
<p id="demo">5</p>
<button onclick="clock()">Start counter</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop counter</button>
```

Comment: `myTimer` only exist inside your function. You need to make it global

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go, you just needed to make `myTimer` global. I also fixed a glitch where after resetting the timer, it won't show 5.

```js
var myTimer;
   function clock() {
     myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
     var c = 5;

     function myClock() {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
       if (c == 0) {
         clearInterval(myTimer);
         alert("Reached zero");
       }
     }
   }
```

```html
<p id="demo">5</p>
<button onclick="clock(); document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML='5';">Start counter</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(myTimer);">Stop counter</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

### Quick and dirty answer

```js
   var myTimer;
   function clock() {
     myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
     var c = 5;

     function myClock() {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
       if (c == 0) {
         clearInterval(myTimer);
         alert("Reached zero");
       }
     }
   }
```

```html
<p id="demo">5</p>
<button onclick="clock()">Start counter</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop counter</button>
```

`timer` in your function (because its declared, `var`, inside your function) can only be accessed inside your function. Moving the `var` declaration outside your function makes it global.

### Better solution

But putting things in the global scope is [(mostly) a bad idea](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad). So.....there's a better way:

```js
   
var myTimerObj = (function(document){
   
   var myTimer;

   function start() {
     myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
     var c = 5;

     function myClock() {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
       if (c == 0) {
         clearInterval(myTimer);
         alert("Reached zero");
       }
     }
   }
   
   function end() {
       clearInterval(myTimer)
   }

   return {start:start, end:end};
 })(document);
```

```html
<p id="demo">5</p>
<button onclick="myTimerObj.start()">Start counter</button>
<button onclick="myTimerObj.end()">Stop counter</button>
```

the better solution utilises a [revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) and will hold the `timer` inside a private scope, **Tl;Dr** it stops the `timer` polluting the global scope.

Comment: all these timers go wonky when you start them with double clicks

Comment: I don't think anyone suggested that this was a full solution. This is simply an answer about scopes

Answer (score 4):

`myTimer` is only in scope within the function. One solution is to make it global.

```js
var myTimer;
function clock() {
     myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
     var c = 5;

     function myClock() {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
       if (c == 0) {
         clearInterval(myTimer);
         alert("Reached zero");
       }
     }
   }
```

```html
<p id="demo">5</p>
<button onclick="clock()">Start counter</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)">Stop counter</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me in react JS

```
let Timer =(function(){
    let timerObject;
    let callback=null;
    let seconds=0;
    let counter=()=>{
        seconds++;
        console.log("seconds",seconds);
        if (callback!==undefined) callback(seconds);
    }
    let setCallback=(_callback)=>{callback=_callback }
    let getSeconds=()=>{ return seconds;}
    let reset=()=>{ seconds=0;}
    let start=()=>{timerObject=setInterval(counter,1000);}
    let end=()=>{clearInterval(timerObject);}
    return {"start":start,"end":end, "getSeconds":getSeconds, "reset":reset,"setCallback":setCallback}; })();

export default Timer;
```