# how to implement start and stop buttons on javascript countdown

Tags: javascript

The following code should start and stop the timer, however the "stop" button is not working. "Play" works fine. it just wont stop

```js
var countDown;

function countDownClock() {
  var timeLeft = 5;
  var text = document.getElementById("countDownTimer");
  var countDown = setInterval(function() {
    if (timeLeft == 0) {
      clearInterval(countDown);
      text.innerHTML = "finished!";
    } else {
      text.innerHTML = timeLeft;
    }
    timeLeft -= 1;
  }, 1000);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="reloadMaths()"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(countDown);"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i></button>
```

do I need to show more JS?

originally i thought this post solved it as I did not have variable as a global variable -however, having made it global this solution is not working
[javascript countdown timer with start & stop buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638402/javascript-countdown-timer-with-start-stop-buttons)

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line
`var countDown = setInterval(function() {`
to
`countDown = setInterval(function() {`

With line 1 you already declared a global var `countDown`. Then in the function you did it again, that's why your clearInterval function won't clear the interval.

Comment: thank you, i completely missed that. been driving me mad!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you have redefined variable `"countDown"` in the `local scope` of the function `"countDownClock"`. The global variable (defined in the first line of your code) will stay undefined, so clearing the interval using `clearInterval(countDown);` is equivalent to `clearInterval(undefined)` what obviously is not what you want to do.

---

Removing the local (re-)declaration of the variable will fix your issues.

**From**

```
var countDown = setInterval(function() { ... })
```

**To**

```
countDown = setInterval(function() { ... })
```

Try out the modified code:

```js
var countDown;

function countDownClock() {
  var timeLeft = 5;
  var text = document.getElementById("countDownTimer");
  countDown = setInterval(function() { // removed var keyword
    if (timeLeft == 0) {
      clearInterval(countDown);
      text.innerHTML = "finished!";
    } else {
      text.innerHTML = timeLeft;
    }
    timeLeft -= 1;
  }, 1000);

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>


<button onclick="countDownClock()"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(countDown);"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i></button>
<div id="countDownTimer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
var countDown;

function countDownClock() {
  var timeLeft = 5;
  var text = document.getElementById("countDownTimer");
  countDown = setInterval(function() {
    if (timeLeft == 0) {
      clearInterval(countDown);
      text.innerHTML = "finished!";
    } else {
      text.innerHTML = timeLeft;
    }
    timeLeft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div id="countDownTimer"></div>

<button onclick="countDownClock()"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(countDown);"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i></button>
```

The main problem with your code was that you redefined countDown in your countDownClock function.  Therefore, when you were doing clearInterval(countDown), you weren't clearing the interval.  You were just clearing an undefined global variable.